# Imprimir texto en formato tabla

Tags: c++, dev-c++, visual-c++

Intento imprimir los resultados de un proyecto de la forma como lo muestra la foto que adjunto, pero pasa que realmente no se porque se me imprimen esos garabatos, lo único que estoy intentando hacer es imprimir todo como en un listado, sin hacer nada de esto todo funciona bien, así que realmente el problema viene con realmente la estética que le estoy planteando a esta parte del programa, pero no se realmente que estoy haciendo mal para que no me imprima correctamente cada cosa aquí mi código, como ven lo único que hice fue asignar espacios a unas variables y luego las imprimí junto a cada arreglo que tiene los datos que voy a imprimir.

```
void resumen(string turismo[], string personas[], string genero[], string peticiones[], string abrevTurismo[], string abrevPersonas[], string abrevGenero[], string abrevPeticiones[], string archivo[], int lineas){
    int anchoturismo = -20, anchopersonas= -15, anchogenero= -15, anchopeticiones = -15, anchofecha= -15;
    try{
        if (archivo[0]=="")
            throw "error"; // Lanzamos error si no ha inicializado el archivo
        int datos[4];
        int fecha[3];
        string abreviaturas[7];

        printf("+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+\n");
        printf("|%*s|%*s|%*s|%*s|%*s|\n", anchoturismo, " Tipo de turismos", anchopersonas,
         " Tipo personas", anchogenero,"Tipo de genero",anchopeticiones,"Peticiones",anchofecha,"FECHA");
        printf("+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+\n");


        //cout<<setw(10)<<"Tipo turismo"<<setw(22)<<"Tipo persona"<<setw(22)<<"Genero"<<setw(22)<<"Peticiones"<<
        //setw(20)<<"Fecha"<<endl;

        for(int i=0 ; i<lineas; i++){
            int index = 0; //Indice del arreglo en el que guardaremos los tokens
            int n = archivo[i].length();//Obtenemos longitud de la linea
            char char_array[n + 1];//Creamos un arreglo de caracteres
            strcpy(char_array, archivo[i].c_str());//Copiamos la linea al arreglo de caracteres
            char *token = strtok(char_array, "&");
            if(token != NULL){
                while(token != NULL){
                    abreviaturas[index] = token;
                    index++;
                    token = strtok(NULL, "&");// Sólo en la primera pasamos la cadena; en las siguientes pasamos NULL
                }
            }
            //Buscamos el indice correspondiente de la abreviatura del archivo
            for(int j=0 ; i<sizeof(abrevTurismo); j++){
                if(abrevTurismo[j] == abreviaturas[0]){
                    datos[0]=j;
                    break;
                }
            }
            for(int j=0 ; i<sizeof(abrevPersonas); j++){
                if(abrevPersonas[j] == abreviaturas[1]){
                    datos[1]=j;
                    break;
                }
            }
            for(int j=0 ; i<sizeof(abrevGenero); j++){
                if(abrevGenero[j] == abreviaturas[2]){
                    datos[2]=j;
                    break;
                }
            }
            for(int j=0 ; i<sizeof(abrevPeticiones); j++){
                if(abrevPeticiones[j] == abreviaturas[3]){
                    datos[3]=j;
                    break;
                }
            }
            //FIN BUSQUEDA
            fecha[0] = hexadecimal_a_decimal(abreviaturas[4]);
            fecha[1] = hexadecimal_a_decimal(abreviaturas[5]);
            fecha[2] = hexadecimal_a_decimal(abreviaturas[6]);
            printf("|%*s|%*s|%*s|%*s|%*s|\n",anchoturismo,turismo[datos[0]],anchopersonas,personas[datos[1]],anchogenero,genero[datos[2]],anchopeticiones,peticiones[datos[3]],anchofecha,to_string(fecha[0])+"/"+to_string(fecha[1])+"/"+to_string(fecha[2]));





        }
    }catch(...){
        cout<<"Ocurrio algun error..."<<endl;
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: imagen de lo que me aparece]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso te pasa por mezclar funciones de C con funciones de C++

`printf` es una función heredada de C y **no tiene** ninguna sobrecarga para `std::string`. Lo raro es que no te esté dando errores de compilación.

Si programas en C++, hazte un favor y haz uso de la funcionalidad propia de C++:

```
#include <iomanip>

std::cout << '|'
          << std::setw(anchoturismo) << turismo[datos[0]]
          << '|'
          << std::setw(anchopersonas) << personas[datos[1]]
          // ...
```

Comment: ajaajaj encerio crei que prientf se podria usar bien en c++ sin ningun tipo de problema

Comment: y crees que todo lo demas este bien ? y es por eso que me esta dando ese error

Comment: estaba probando tu idea @eferion pero realmente me funciono pero tenes alguna idea para mejorar el orden de cada cosa? sinceramente la funcion setw y yo no somos amigas, si notas en mi codigo tengo un codigo comentado con setw pero realmente no me ordena nada setw por eso intente esta otra forma, y lo que me dijiste me ayudo pero ahora no me ordenada nada osea me lo muestra todo como lo ves tu en la foto que agregue, tienes alguna sugerencia?

Comment: @EstherPorta ordenar el que, ¿los resultados? para mostrar los resultados ordenados debes ordenar esa lista **antes** de mostrarla en pantalla

Comment: que idea me darias para lograr hacerlo @eferion?

Comment: @EstherPorta no crees que sería mejor elaborar una pregunta nueva?